# executing a photoshop script (jsx) from a python script

Tags: python, photoshop-script

TL;DR - is it possible to run photoshop scripts from outside photoshop on a specific .psd file?

Hi,

I'm building an automation that takes layers from photoshop and saves them to textures.
In addition to the textures, I need to have a .json descriptor with the data of the transform component of the layer - position, scale, rotation.

For the .json part I already have the script (.jsx) attached to photoshop and I can run it from photoshop itself.

My question is: Is it possible to run my .jsx photoshop script from my python script?*

*im using "psd_tools" library in my python exe.

thanks in advance

I've already tried looking in the psd_tools library for answers, and looked for ways to invoke scripts from my python files. I'm now struggling to get more info about this.
Thanks.

Comment: read [this](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/using-photoshop-action-scripts-in-command-line/m-p/6036169)

Comment: If you're not running _in_ Photoshop, using [the modern Node API](https://blog.developer.adobe.com/introducing-the-adobe-photoshop-api-sdk-for-node-js-developers-b47fa8a00fa2?gi=c06a6ebb8d1c) probably makes more sense than trying to use the legacy JavaScript 1.5 based jsx scripting approach